# Integrity Error after submission of Registration using Django 2.0

Tags: python, django

I keep on getting an Integrity Error (FOREIGN KEY constrain failed) after registration.

```
from django.db import models
from .user import User
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/pictures/', blank=True)
    regex = RegexValidator(r'^\d{2}/\d{4}',
                           message='Required. 7 characters or fewer. This value must contain only numeric and slash.')
    matric_no = models.CharField(validators=[regex], blank=False, max_length=7, unique=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
                                 message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True)  # validators should be a list
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
            ('M', 'Male'),
            ('F', 'Female'),
        )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=False, default='M',)
```

forms.py

```
class StudentProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    avatar = forms.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('avatar', 'phone_number', 'address', 'gender', 'matric_no')
```

views.py

```
class StudentRegistrationView(CreateView):
    model = Student
    form_class = StudentProfileForm
    template_name = 'registration.html'

    def student_registration(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = StudentProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                register = form.save(False)
                register.save()
                return redirect('home')

        else:
            form = StudentProfileForm()
        return render(request, 'accounts/registration.html', {'form': form})
```

What I think the problem might probably be is matric_no field, or what did you think?

Comment: Please meticulously copy and paste the error message/s here, making it/them stand out as a *block quote* (for starters, there's a typo in your 1st rendition). Try to provide an [mcve] how to reproduce the error.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

`user` is a `OneToOneField`, not nullable, and it's not in the form, so you need to assign it. Conveniently, you are already doing steps 1 and 3 of the solution (saving the form with commit `False` and then saving the instance), so you only need to add the missing step:

```
if form.is_valid():
    register = form.save(commit=False)
    register.user = request.user
    register.save()
```

Comment: This registration form is form that output immediately after signup does I need to add register.user = request.user?

Comment: `register.save()` is saving a `Student` instance to the database, with the contents of the form. You need to add the user before you save, since it doesn't exist in `register` and there's no other way for the code to infer which user you want.

Comment: it seems not work for me in such context due to the user have to login before Student registration being filled up and without that i will be getting an Integrity Error... Is there a way i can add "matric_no" to a signup form with OneToOneField?

Comment: Oh, the user is not signed up yet. `matric_no` is not an issue, as far as I can see, as long as the user fills out that field (which can be validated). What you absolutely must have before creating the `Student` in the database is a `User` instance that you can save. You could do that after signup (which you don't show here), or do it all in the same page, getting the instance of the newly created user and adding it to `register`.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem using signal in my model and written my view this way

view.py

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StudentSignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user_obj = form.save(commit=False)
            user_obj.set_password(form.cleaned_data.get('password1'))
            user_obj.save()
            user_login = auth.authenticate(username=user_obj.username, password=form.cleaned_data.get('password1'))
            login(request, user_login)
            return redirect('student_register')
    else:
        form = StudentSignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/signup_form.html', {'form': form})
```

model.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Student.objects.create(user=instance)
```